# Running awk inside of tox

Tags: python, tox

I've configured the following command as a command in tox.

```
bash -c "ps | awk '{print $1}'"
```

Because uses `{}` for substitution I get a tox configuration error saying that print $1 does not exist. Is there a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the documentation on substitutions](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=substitution#substitutions)

> You can escape curly braces with the \ character if you need them, for example:
>
> ```
> commands = echo "\{posargs\}" = {posargs}
> ```

---

disclaimer: I'm one of the tox maintainers